# CSS :: How to disable scrolling in list cells

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm currently developing an Ionic Cordova mobile application, and I used the ion-scroll property in order for my list to become scrollable. Unfortunately, even the table inside the list itself is also scrollable. Is there any way to disable this? I just want the list itself to be scrollable not the table inside the individual cells.

```css
  .collection-container {
  width: 150%;
  margin-left: -15.7px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  .button {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
  }
  .item {
    border-bottom: 0.55px solid color($colors, border);
    background-color: lightskyblue !important;
    height: 100px;
  }
  ion-scroll {
    margin-left: -17px;
    margin-top: -9.5px;
    width: 200%;
  }
  th {
    float: left;
    color: rgb(4, 38, 150);
  }
  td {
    float: right;
    color: rgb(4, 38, 150);
  }
  .checkbox {
    float: left;
    margin: 35px;
    margin-left: 8px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="collection-container">
  <ion-scroll style="width:100%;height:90vh" scrollY="true">
    <ion-list class="dataList" scroll="true">
      <ion-content class="item" *ngFor="let item of collection">
        <ion-checkbox class="checkbox"></ion-checkbox>
        <table class="dataDisplay">
          <tr>
            <th>NAME OF MOTHER: </th>
            <td>{{ item.nameMother }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>NAME OF CHILD: </th>
            <td>{{ item.nameChild }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>DATE OF BIRTH (MM/DD/YYYY):</th>
            <td>{{ item.birthDate | date }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>FORM COMPLETE: </th>
            <td>{{ item.Form }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Countdown: </th>
            <td><strong>{{ item.countdown }}</strong></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-scroll>
</div>
```

Comment: overflow-y: hidden; in the table

Comment: I've done this already :( unfortunately, it doesn't stop the scrolling. Thanks anyways for answering.